# Backporting "{n:,d}".format() to Python 2.6

Tags: python, formatting

The "thousands separator" in Python [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) (comma in `"{n:,d}"`) was added in v2.7:

```
$ python2.7 -c 'print "{n:,d}".format(n=1234567890)'
1,234,567,890
```

I have a lot of code using it which I have to run under 2.6 (because that's what CentOS 6.4 ships) and which now fails:

```
$ python2.6 -c 'print "{n:,d}".format(n=1234567890)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid conversion specification
```

**What are my options?**

[StringFormat](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/StringFormat) [fails](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi/issue/251/stringformat-n-d-invalid-conversion):

```
>>> import stringformat
>>> stringformat.init(True)
>>> "{n:,d}".format(n=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/stringformat.py", line 326, in format
    return FormattableString(self).format(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/stringformat.py", line 267, in format
    want_bytes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/stringformat.py", line 159, in _format_field
    value = value.__format__(spec)
ValueError: Invalid conversion specification
```

Comment: Try StringFormat (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/StringFormat)

Comment: @dhke: [nope](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi/issue/251/stringformat-n-d-invalid-conversion), sorry.

Comment: What about `print "{:,}".format(123456)`?

Comment: @ForceBru: `ValueError: Unknown format code ',' for object of type 'int'`